# Pyvmomi: Permission denied on vcenter

Tags: python, vmware, pyvmomi

I'm trying to run some sample scripts from the Pyvmomi Community Samples on a vcenter server appliance:
https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples

> Caught vmodl fault : Permission to perform this operation was denied.

With another simple script:

```
from pyVim.connect import SmartConnect, Disconnect
import ssl

s = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
s.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

c = SmartConnect(host="IP", user="USER", pwd='PWD', sslContext=s)

datacenter = c.content.rootFolder.childEntity[0]
vms = datacenter.vmFolder.childEntity

for i in vms:
    print(i.name)

Disconnect(c)
```

If I use my domain user account, with which I can login to the vcenter:

> Cannot complete login due to an incorrect user name or password.

I used DOMAIN\USERNAME as user.

or as root:

> Permission to perform this operation was denied.

I added some permissions in vcenter server, but apparently it is not enough :(.

Comment: Unless what you have in your example is a typo the password param is wrong. Its missing a comma.

Comment: I have the same issue. It works with one user but not the other. Both users have seemingly have the same permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue, I added port it worked.
Need to add port as the parameter,
Change this

```
SmartConnect(host="IP", user="USER", pwd='PWD', sslContext=s)
```

to

```
import ssl
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
SmartConnect(host="IP", user="USER", pwd='PWD', port=443, sslContext=context)
```

Comment: This doesn't help me. Here's [my](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75506100/unable-to-query-vms-on-vcenter-server-appliance-using-pyvmomi) question. Could you please take a look at it and see if I am missing something obvious?